# Algorithm to find the closest summation of elements in a list to a given number

Tags: algorithms

Say I have a list {1,3,7,2,11,8,2} and I want to take x elements from the list and get the value 15.5.

Is there an algorithm that would give me x elements in a list that, when added together, get nearest to this given value?

There is no preferred amount of elements, I just want to get as close to the given as possible.

I plan on implementing this algorithm in Swift (Object Oriented) if that makes any difference.

Comment: This is the [subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) which is well studied.

Comment: You say *list* and your list is *obviously not sorted*. Intentionally?

Answer (score 0):

For a small dataset and a fixed value for the total and the number of elements, I would just do a modified brute force that was based on enumerating all the x number elements and discarding each less optimal solution as you go.  I wouldn't bother to over-optimize it.

If you're talking about a changing data set and repeated variances of x and quantity, then I would start looking for more advanced options.

Comment: I am thinking about using an iTunes library as the dataset and a user controlled x. So optimizing the algorithm would definitely be the ideal solution.